# Performance of multiple HttpClient async requests

Tags: c#

I am having issues with performance of HttpClient async requests.
I want to make multiple requests to different IPs and get JSON API content as string.

When i am using single instance, after ~3 requests performance is going down.
When i am using disposed it is acceptable for one, but not for multiple requests.

Here is my code and results:

```
private static readonly HttpClient ClientPublic = new HttpClient();        
public async Task<string> GetURL(string url)
{            
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string URLString = await ClientPublic.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    watch.Stop(); 

    addtolist(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), url);
    return URLString;
}
```

Result of single URL (ms): 205 155 640 640 590 651 681 590

```
public async Task<string> GetURL2(string url)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    using (var ClientPublic2 = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var result = await ClientPublic2.GetAsync(url))
        {
            string URLString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            watch.Stop();
            addtolist(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), url);
        }
    }            
    return URLString;
}
```

Result of single URL (ms): 208 686 198 190 141 271 131 119

When im doing calls for multiple (10) URL's in general one instance method give better results, but there are always 2-3 requests with pretty high response time.

I checked requestd URLs via browser addon and all responses are < 200ms.
Is there anything on what i could look for diagnose this issue?

Comment: Since you are calling over HTTP, are you 100% sure the slowdown is in your code? How long do responses usually take for the server handling the request?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i tried ARC Chrome addon for perform requests from  browser, and all responses there are < 200 ms.

Comment: Are you starting the requests one after another or simultaneously?

Comment: They all are started in same time in task + async. But this issue appear even for single URL from task, after a few requests.

Comment: Have you considered using a semaphore (or something similar) to limit the number of concurrent requests (at least per target), or are all targets on different servers? Also, are you using any potentially blocking operations in the code you didn't include (e.g. in `addtolist`)? By the way, your browser most likely doesn't close the connection to the server between requests and doesn't request everything at once.

Comment: They all are sent to different IP targets (my servers for bypass API limits). There are no thread blocking things, addtolist is doing  Debug.Write to Immediate Window. I also checked how browser act, after getting response connection is instantly closed.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @levent, i know this article, and as you can see i also used this method (one instance)

Comment: Ok! I guess i figured it out. `ClientPublic.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;` This helped a lot, i guess c# app/win just did not closed connection enough fast due to overload of calls and server do not handled it good.

Comment: I'd expect it to be slower with ConnectionClose, because then you have pefomance hit of opening and closing connection on every request.

Comment: It is making really slight difference if so i guess, 15-30ms per request, since they are sent in tasks it should be just same delay in general, but definitly better than 500ms in previous case. Im looking now into http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.htmlarticle for check ConnectionLeaseTimeout for keept instance for required parallel connections.